# What is the time complexity for solving $Ax = b$ if $A$ is a Hessenberg matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's say that we are given a matrix $A$ in the Hessenberg form (The only nonzero elements of the matrix are positioned in the upper triangle and one row below it).

Now, we need to solve the equation:

$$Ax = b$$ where

with respect to $x$, where

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $x,b \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$

I am thinking what the most optimal way to do this is.

I believe that we can solve it using Gaussian Elimination in linear time. In every column, we need to eliminate exactly one element. We repeat this process for each column.

Then, we perform backwards-substitution using the Gaussian-reduced matrix.

Is it the right way to tackle this problem? Are there any issues with this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of the one sided reduction of a Hessenberg matrix to triangular form is not linear, but quadratic in the dimension of the matrix. While we only eliminate one entry per column, we do need to update an entire row for every entry eliminated. Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting or Givens rotations are both viable options. My first choice would be Givens rotations because orthogonal transformations preserve the norm of errors.